# Sending large files with hub

Tags: hub

Suppose we have a 10Mbps half-duplex hub and we want to send a 1GB file. it takes about 13.5 minutes for the transfer to be finished. Could the other computers connected to this hub, communicate with each other between the frames or not? I mean like a round-robin or token-ring technology?

Note 1: I know that 2 computers could not talk at the same time on hub, I mean for example PC1 sends 10 frames, then pauses, PC2 sends 1 frame, then PC1 resumes sending the remaining frames.

Note 2: By hub, I don't mean switch or unmanaged switch, I really mean hubs from 80s.

Comment: Note: [P.S. and P.P.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript) are pretty much obsolete in modern electronic communications as any afterthoughts can easily be edited into the main body of the work.

Answer (score 3):

Ethernet hubs use [CSMA/CD](http://study-ccna.com/csma-cd/) technology not Round Robin or Token Ring. 
As such each node attached to the hub will get access using the 'normal' sense/ send /collision detect/ back off & retry mechanism. This will allow them all to communicate, they all get the opportunity to send.

> P.S. I know that 2 computers could not talk at the same time on hub, I mean for example PC1 sends 10 frames, then pauses, PC2 sends 1 frame, then PC1 resumes sending the remaining frames.

This is  not how an ethernet hub works A hub should be considered an extension of the ethernet medium. Each station will listen to determine if the medium is clear. It will then send 1 packet. After sending a packet it again listens which gives other stations the opportunity to send...